# Should I use oracle partition if i have to query using column not used in partition clause

Tags: oracle, performance, partitioning

I have a customer table containing 200 million records. There are three sources of customers (70 million, 80 million and 50 million records).

I have three queries on this table.

- One which fetches customer details based on `customerid` and `source`.
- Second to fetch customer details based on `source` and `accountid`.
- Third to fetch customer details by mobile number.

Should I use list partition on this table, where I partition by `source`? The query to fetch customer by mobile number would become slow after partitioning. It takes a long time to insert records without partition.

Following columns are present in customer table:

```
customerid number(12), 
source varchar2(100), 
accountid number(12), 
mobile number(10).
```

Each customer record will have distinct `customerid`, `source` and `accountid` combination.

Comment: For future reference, please use thousands and millions for large numbers rather lakh and crore, as the latter terms are not common outside India.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use oracle partition if i have to query using column not used in partition clause

Probably not. Partitioning is primarily a management tool, for wrangling large amounts of data and keeping it available. The performance impact of Partitioning can be negative as well as positive, especially for queries which do not filter on the Partitioning key (as is the case with your query on mobile number).

Anyway, I doubt Partitioning on `source` will make much improvement to the performance of *any* of your queries. It just isn't selective enough for partition pruning to give a noticeable benefit.

What might be more useful would be compound indexes on `(source, customerid)` and `(source, accountid)` with `compress 1` in both cases. It's worth compressing the leading column of the index precisely because `source` is so unselective. Also a single column index on `(mobile)` (with no compression).

Incidentally, why is `source` defined as **varchar2(100)**? That seems insanely long for what is a trivalent identifier. It ought to be a one (or two or three) character code (with a lookup table for the full description if required). I think that might explain why it *"takes a long time to insert records without partition"*. Tackling that should be the focus of your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, `no partition + indexes` on those columns would be my choice (having  information you provided).

Moreover, "partition" means "a lot of money" as you have to have Enterprise Edition (EE), and partitioning is (as far as I can tell) an add-on to already expensive EE. So ... I'm not suggesting that you (or your company) don't have that money, but pointing out that it might become an issue.